# Haskell Crypto Hash SHA256 replit failure

Tags: haskell, hash, sha256, replit

I'm trying to hash text using Crypto.Hash modules on replit.com, I don't know how to resolve this failure: Could not find module ‘Crypto.Hash’

Code:

```
import Crypto.Hash (hashWith, SHA256(..))
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)


main = do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  putStrLn "World"
  hashWith SHA256 ("hello" :: ByteString)
```

I will be very grateful for your help!!!

Comment: Haskell / GHC doesn't come with any crypto stuff. The `Crypto.Hash` module you want is (probably) the one from [the `cryptonite` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.29/docs/Crypto-Hash.html), so you need to depend on that package. Not sure if that's possible on replit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `replit.com` is Nix based, and it uses a `replit.nix` configuration file to configure the Nix environment, including loaded GHC packages.

So, one way to get this working is to edit the `replit.nix` file.  (By default, it won't be shown in the "Files" tab, but you can click the vertical "..." in the top-right corner and select "Show hidden files" to view it.)  Modify it to look something like:

```
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        (pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (pkgs: [
          pkgs.cryptonite
        ]))
        pkgs.haskell-language-server
    ];
}
```

Now, when you run the source, it should reconfigure the Nix environment and load the required `cryptonite` package.  You may need to modify your code slightly, too, as it uses an `OverloadedStrings` extension, and `hashWith` isn't an IO action.  I got the following `Main.hs` to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Crypto.Hash (hashWith, SHA256(..))
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

main = do
  print $ hashWith SHA256 ("hello" :: ByteString)
```

Comment: Finally it works. Your advice was very helpful for me! Thank you very much!!!